# Do scooter/moped licensing laws apply across state lines?

Tags: driving, motor-vehicle, interstate-travel

In the US, in my home state (call it HS), it's explicitly legal to ride a 50cc scooter/moped on the street without a driver's license. Let's say I have no license and drive my scooter into some other state (call it OS), which requires a driver's license and/or a motorcycle license or endorsement to ride a 50cc scooter. Am I legally allowed to drive it on OS roads? I know that if it were a larger motorcycle and I had an appropriate license issued by HS, the Full Faith and Credit Clause would compel OS to respect my license, but does this also apply to the case where there is no license, and OS has to decide whether to respect HS's lack of requirement?

**Note:** I am not asking about whether or not a given state can require drivers to have a license, I'm asking how a state licensing law applies to residents of other states who are travelling or visiting. States have widely varying laws around what license classes are required for various vehicle classes, and I'm asking how these differences are resolved when touring across state lines. Do I have to get the maximum level of certification that would apply across every state on my route?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to operate a vehicle without a license in the purpose of traveling](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/is-it-legal-to-operate-a-vehicle-without-a-license-in-the-purpose-of-traveling)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch no, and I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yes, "States have widely varying laws". That makes your question too broad. It's best to simply look at each state's DMV requirements on the web.

Comment: I once got a ticket for driving without a hands-free device in NYC. This isn't illegal in my home state, but that doesn't matter. You need to abide by the laws of the state you are in, not just those you live in.

Comment: @RonBeyer the difference I see is that hands-free devices are not state-specific, while license types are. It's reasonable to expect you to have a hands-free device when entering NYC, but it's not reasonable to expect you to have an NY-issued drivers license. In the case of cars, the validity of an out-of-state license seems pretty clear cut, but when it comes to motorcycles there are more complexities, for instance motorcycle licenses independent of a car license, or licenses authorizing you to drive with a sidecar.